# New Android Studio project (module) with an older SDK version

Tags: android, android-studio

I've scoured Stack Overflow and the interwebs to no avail, so I thought I would create my first question.

The problem is this: With previous versions of Android Studio I could choose the targetedSDKVersion and compliedSDKVersion when creating the project, the latest stable version on my Mac (v1.3.2) doesn't allow this.

Instead, it defaults to using the most recently installed version. Even if I change the build.gradle settings to an older sdk, it has problems with finding some elements and styles, which makes sense for different sdk versions.

So my question is:
**How can I create a new Android Studio project with an older compiledSDKVersion?**

My ultimate purpose is to have an Android Studio project that I and a couple of others can work on from multiple computers. (We'll be using Git but I prefer not to use the built-in VCS features, I just don't want to add new confusing concepts to something that should be simple).

Thanks for any assistance, I'll do what I can to clarify if requested.

Comment: Do you have the older SDKs installed?

Comment: Yeah, definitely: 23, 22 and 21

Comment: There should not be an issue then. What code gives you errors?

Comment: For instance, I've just created a new Project: Blank Activity, default settings.

I go to the build.gradle for the module and change:  
    `compileSdkVersion 22 //from 23`  
   `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" //from 23.0.1`

Comment: The resultant error when trying to sync gradle is     
<br>`Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.`

Comment: You don't need to lower the buildtoolsversion, the newest version should always be the best, regardless of SDK versions you are supporting

Comment: Just tried it, same problem.
What you mention makes sense to me too, I changed the build tools version cos I saw a suggestion that when using an older sdk, the older version of the build tools may fix some errors

Comment: I find it all very weird. Have you considered reinstalling the IDE and SDK?

Comment: Yeah, I know right. It used to be very straight-forward. I don't see any benefit in reinstalling, it's a fresh install as it is, and I have similar issues on the other computers I've used (iMacs at uni)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent a good part of the last day trying to do exactly this -- I have only a Kitkat device available and wanted to step into the SDK source to see what was going on.

I've concluded that you simply can't do it in Studio.  The template project that Studio creates for you presumes a large number of v21 resources.  After my forehead was sufficiently sore, I was able to create a new v19 project with Eclipse/ADT, and import it to Studio.

It compiles and runs, but probably doesn't do what you want; the v19 SDK source file line numbers in my SDK don't precisely match the v19 libraries on my device, so I can't step into them